Can Unreal Engine's Movie Render Queue set the paths of two output images?
I'm using Unreal Engine's Movie Render Queue to render images, and I'm using a network storage path. It's not uncommon for online drives to be disconnected for any reason, and Unreal Engine crashes due to invalid output paths.
Whether it is possible to set an alternate output path for the Movie Render Queue, that is, to dump the pictures to path B if path A fails？

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
